# Detect finger switch on touch

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a bitmap that I can drag around on my app, but there is a small bug, if let's say someone clicks with one finger on the bitmap and starts moving it around, and then while moving it around clicks with another finger, the bitmap "teleports" over there. How can I detect if the user switched fingers so bitmaps wont teleport? this is my Action_MOVE code:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (dragging) {
                CurrentMobEntry.getKey().x = (int) x
                        - CurrentMobEntry.getValue().getNormalbit()
                                .getWidth() / 2; 
                CurrentMobEntry.getKey().y = (int) y
                        - CurrentMobEntry.getValue().getNormalbit()
                                .getHeight() / 2;
                CurrentMobEntry.getValue().getDestroyedP().x=(int)x
                        +CurrentMobEntry.getValue().getNormalbit()
                        .getWidth() / 2;
                CurrentMobEntry.getValue().getDestroyedP().y = (int)y
                + CurrentMobEntry.getValue().getNormalbit()
                        .getHeight() / 2;
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Is there no finger data that you're pulling from? Or are using a higher level framework that translates touches into a very simple format? A lot of touch handling things I've worked with break touches into "fingers" (basically each touch represents a single finger) and then I generally use the first finger for things like what you're talking about. This would prevent a "second" finger from messing with your location calculations.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html):

Some devices can report multiple movement traces at the same time. Multi-touch screens emit one movement trace for each finger. The individual fingers or other objects that generate movement traces are referred to as **pointers**. Motion events contain information about all of the pointers that are currently active even if some of them have not moved since the last event was delivered.

**The number of pointers only ever changes by one as individual pointers go up and down, except when the gesture is canceled.**

So what you want to do is to allow only for one **pointer** (finger) to operate in any given time. I can't seem to find a simple solution to this so we are going to use a workaround:

Each pointer gets a unique, constant ID. On any given touch event, you will check to see if that pointer initiated the event and then if true consume it, else ignore.

For a full example of this check the Android Developer's [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html).